# Selenium by.xpath иногда получаю пустые данные

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

ситуация такая:
таблица имеет скроллбар, я ее прокручиваю до конца и считываю данные,
делаю запрос, получаю значение тега все в порядке (код html  Пример 1)
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table//tbody)[last()]/tr[1]/td[3]")).getText();

Если прокрутить таблицу вверх а потом вниз (обновить данные), перестаю получать значение тега (код html Пример 2)

Не пойму в чем дело, может кто то подсказать?
премногоблагодарен
Пример 1 ->

```html
<table><colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup><thead><tr><td>#&nbsp;Сделки</td><td>Тип</td><td>Сигнал</td><td class="date">Дата/Время</td><td>Цена</td><td>Контракты</td><td>Прибыль</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1203</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в короткую позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Short</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;05:39</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.30370</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">259540.4</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 236.18<div class="additional_percent_value">0.31&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из короткой позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;05:48</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.30279</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1204</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;08:06</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29912</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">252160.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 5.04<div class="additional_percent_value">0.01&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;08:21</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29914</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1205</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;08:18</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29821</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">252160.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 234.51<div class="additional_percent_value">0.31&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;08:21</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29914</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1206</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:15</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29884</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253038.2</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit"><span class="neg">$ 25.30</span><div class="additional_percent_value"><span class="neg">0.03&nbsp;%</span></div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:24</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29874</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1207</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:18</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29809</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253038.2</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 164.47<div class="additional_percent_value">0.22&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:24</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29874</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1208</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:39</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29780</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">254423.3</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 25.44<div class="additional_percent_value">0.03&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:48</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29790</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1209</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;10:15</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29725</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">254971.2</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 112.19<div class="additional_percent_value">0.15&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;10:18</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29769</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1210</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в короткую позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Short</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;10:54</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29970</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253235.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit"><span class="neg">$ 75.97</span><div class="additional_percent_value"><span class="neg">0.1&nbsp;%</span></div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из короткой позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:15</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.30000</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1211</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в короткую позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Short</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:00</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29979</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253235.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit"><span class="neg">$ 53.18</span><div class="additional_percent_value"><span class="neg">0.07&nbsp;%</span></div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из короткой позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:15</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.30000</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1212</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в короткую позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Short</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:03</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.30036</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253235.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 91.16<div class="additional_percent_value">0.12&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из короткой позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:15</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.30000</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Пример 2 ->

```html
<table><colgroup><col><col><col><col><col><col><col></colgroup><thead><tr><td>#&nbsp;Сделки</td><td>Тип</td><td>Сигнал</td><td class="date">Дата/Время</td><td>Цена</td><td>Контракты</td><td>Прибыль</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1204</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;08:06</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29912</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">252160.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 5.04<div class="additional_percent_value">0.01&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;08:21</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29914</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1205</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;08:18</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29821</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">252160.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 234.51<div class="additional_percent_value">0.31&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;08:21</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29914</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1206</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:15</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29884</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253038.2</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit"><span class="neg">$ 25.30</span><div class="additional_percent_value"><span class="neg">0.03&nbsp;%</span></div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:24</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29874</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1207</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:18</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29809</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253038.2</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 164.47<div class="additional_percent_value">0.22&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:24</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29874</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1208</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:39</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29780</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">254423.3</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 25.44<div class="additional_percent_value">0.03&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;09:48</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29790</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1209</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в длинную позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Long</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;10:15</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29725</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">254971.2</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 112.19<div class="additional_percent_value">0.15&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из длинной позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;10:18</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.29769</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1210</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в короткую позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Short</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;10:54</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29970</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253235.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit"><span class="neg">$ 75.97</span><div class="additional_percent_value"><span class="neg">0.1&nbsp;%</span></div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из короткой позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:15</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.30000</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1211</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в короткую позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Short</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:00</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.29979</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253235.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit"><span class="neg">$ 53.18</span><div class="additional_percent_value"><span class="neg">0.07&nbsp;%</span></div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из короткой позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:15</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.30000</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1212</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в короткую позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Short</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:03</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.30036</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253235.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 91.16<div class="additional_percent_value">0.12&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из короткой позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:15</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.30000</td></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><td rowspan="2" class="trade-num">1212</td><td class="trade-e-type">Вход в короткую позицию</td><td class="trade-e-comment comment">Short</td><td class="trade-e-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:03</td><td class="trade-e-price">0.30036</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-contracts">253235.7</td><td rowspan="2" class="trade-profit">$ 91.16<div class="additional_percent_value">0.12&nbsp;%</div></td></tr><tr><td class="trade-x-type">Выход из короткой позиции</td><td class="trade-x-comment comment">Close position order</td><td class="trade-x-date">2019-04-26&nbsp;11:15</td><td class="trade-x-price">0.30000</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: более точно - получаю пустую структуру, до вышеописанных действий все в порядке

Answer (score -1):

Решил так

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table//tbody)[last()]/tr[1]/td[3]")).getAttribute("textContent");
```